# Добавить изображение в анонсы элемента

Tags: php, битрикс

**Доброго времени суток**
Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить image в Анонсы элемента?
Я делаю так:

```
 $arFieldsElement = Array(
     "ACTIVE" => "Y",
     "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => $arrElementOffer['ID'],
     "IBLOCK_ID" => 188,
     "NAME" => $arrFilterOffer['name'],
     "UF_CATEGORY_ID" => $arrFilterOffer['id'],
     "PREVIEW_PICTURE" => $arrFilterOffer['image'][0]
 );
 $el->Add($arFieldsElement) <br>
```

Но image не добавляется в анонсы.

Comment: `$arrFilterOffer['image'][0]` содержит __что__?

Comment: @u_mulder здравствуйте. $arrFilterOffer['image'][0] содержит ссылку на изображение которое на другом сайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт.
Нужно использовать MakeFileArray(), который спарсит по url изображение и поместит его в upload во временную папку.

```
    $arFieldsElement = Array(
                                 "ACTIVE" => "Y",
                                 "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => $arrElementOffer['ID'],
                                 "IBLOCK_ID" => 188,
                                 "NAME" => $arrFilterOffer['name'],
                                 "UF_CATEGORY_ID" => $arrFilterOffer['id'],
                                 "PREVIEW_PICTURE" => CFile::MakeFileArray($arrFilterOffer['image'][0])
);
```